# Understanding the wss.clients object in the ws npm package

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, ws

I am working with the npm ws library on a Node.js server. I was looking at the documentation and found a way to loop through the clients to, for example, send a message to everyone using the `wss.clients` object:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.server({ port:8080 });
//...
wss.clients.forEach(client => {
  client.send("A message to you!");
});
```

I initially thought that `wss.clients` was an array because it let me iterate through it with the array prototype `forEach()`, but when I tried running `wss.clients.find()` on it to send a message only to a specific connection, I got an error:

```
TypeError: wss.clients.find is not a function
```

I ran `console.log(Array.isArray(wss.clients))` it said *false*. When I tried `console.log(wss.clients)`, I got an object looking like this:

```
Set { WebSocket { ... } }
```

So, my question is, how is the `wss.clients` *object* able to run the *array* prototype `forEach()`? It worked without using `Object.keys()` or anything.
I also tried `wss.clients.pop()` out of curiosity, and it gave another type error.

What really is `wss.clients`? An object or an array?

Comment: it is Set not Array

Comment: Oh... I didn't realize that the `Set` object had the `forEach()` method on it, but not other array methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have discovered (thanks to @waiaan) that the type of `wss.clients` is a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).
Sets have different methods than arrays, but they are similar.

The best implementation for Set.prototype.find() would be to define a method like this:

```
Set.prototype.find = function(cb) {
    for (const e of this) {
        if (cb(e)) {
            return e;
        }
    }
}
```

More about arrays and sets in [this article](https://codeburst.io/array-vs-set-vs-map-vs-object-real-time-use-cases-in-javascript-es6-47ee3295329b).